# How to filter to all variants of a generic type using OfType<>

Tags: c#, linq, generics, filter, oftype

**I want to filter objects in a `List<ISeries>` using their type, using OfType<>.** My problem is, that some objects are of a generic interface type, but they do not have a common inherited interface of their own. 

I have the following definitions:

```
public interface ISeries
public interface ITraceSeries<T> : ISeries
public interface ITimedSeries : ISeries
//and some more...
```

My list contains all kinds of `ISeries`, but now I want to get only the `ITraceSeries` objects, regardless of their actually defined generic type parameter, like so:

```
var filteredList = myList.OfType<ITraceSeries<?>>(); //invalid argument!
```

**How can I do that?**

An unfavored solution would be to introduce a type `ITraceSeries` that inherits from `ISeries`:

```
public interface ITraceSeries<T> : ITraceSeries
```

Then, use `ITraceSeries` as filter. But this does not really add new information, but only make the inheritance chain more complicated.

It seems to me like a common problem, but I did not find useful information on SO or the web. Thanks for help!

Comment: Think about what the return type of `myList.OfType` should be.

Comment: It should be IEnumerable<ISeries>. But this is a good point, how to tell that to the OfType<> method!?

Comment: The return type of OfType is the same as the type parameter.

Comment: @Martinho Nit: it returns an IEnumerable of the type parameter

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use reflection to achieve it:

```
var filteredList = myList.Where(
    x => x.GetType()
          .GetInterfaces()
          .Any(i => i.IsGenericType && (i.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(ITraceSeries<>))));
```

Comment: Great stuff! However, I thought, I could reduce complexity... Now my complexity is hidden in a remote space, not in the inheritance structure! :-)

Comment: Can you tell me what typeof(ITraceSeries<>) actually returns as type? As far as I know, generic typed classes do not share a common base class. (This was my source of trouble in the first place)

Comment: @Marcel: `typeof(ITraceSeries<>)` returns an open generic type for `ITraceSeries<T>`. You cannot declare objects of that type, but you can use that to make closed types like `ITraceSeries<string>`.

Comment: @Martinho: Just to be picky, technically typeof<I<>> is better characterized as an *unbound* generic type. Whether a type is open or closed depends on whether it has any unsubstituted type parameters in it; for example, I<T[]> is bound but open. I<int[]> is bound and closed, I<> is unbound.

Answer (score 3):

```
from s in series
where s.GetType().GetGenericTypeDefinition()==typeof(ITraceSeries<>)
select s;
```

Comment: Good idea, but it won't work exactly like that because `typeof(ITraceSeries<string>) != typeof(ITraceSeries<>)`. Fixed it.

Comment: :-) Much of the answers is just ideas - direction to the right solution. Thanks for correction.

Comment: @Martinho: That still won't work because `GetType` will return a concrete, runtime type and that type will never be `ITraceSeries<something>`, it'll be a concrete implementation of `ITraceSeries<something>`. See my answer for a solution that should, hopefully meet the OP's requirements.