# How to filter with types of generic interfaces in Linq?

Tags: c#, linq, generics

I need to process all variants of a generic interface in a list.

In the following example there are `DerivedPerson` that each holds a references to its `PersonTemplate`.

```
internal interface ITemplate
{
    int TemplateID { get; set; }
}

internal class PersonTemplate : ITemplate
{
    public PersonTemplate(int templateId)
    {
        TemplateID = templateId;
    }

    public int TemplateID { get; set; }
}

internal interface ITemplateInstance<TTemplate> where TTemplate : ITemplate
{
    TTemplate TemplateReference { get; set; }
}

internal class DerivedPerson : ITemplateInstance<PersonTemplate>
{
    public DerivedPerson(PersonTemplate template)
    {
        TemplateReference = template;
    }

    public PersonTemplate TemplateReference { get; set; }
}

internal class Program
{
    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        IList<object> objects = new List<object>
        {
            new object(),
            new DerivedPerson(new PersonTemplate(1)),
            new DerivedPerson(new PersonTemplate(2))
        };

        //Count = 2
        List<ITemplate> personTemplates = objects
                                            .OfType<ITemplateInstance<PersonTemplate>>()
                                            .Select(pi => pi.TemplateReference as ITemplate)
                                            .ToList();

        //Count = 0 (!)
        List<ITemplate> allTemplates = objects
                                            .OfType<ITemplateInstance<ITemplate>>()
                                            .Select(pi => pi.TemplateReference)
                                            .ToList();
    }
}
```

In the `Main` method I want to process all instances of any template not only those of type `PersonTemplate`. I'm searching for a generic method that can handle that.

I found a similar and already accepted question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6071325/how-to-filter-to-all-variants-of-a-generic-type-using-oftype). But my goal is not to proceed with a filtered `IList<object>` but with an `IList<ITemplate>`

Comment: Well an `ITemplateInstance<PersonTemplate>` simply *isn't* an `ITemplateInstance<ITemplate>>` - you wouldn't be able to cast from one to the other, for example. If `TemplateReference` were read-only, you could declare `ITemplateReference<out T>` which would work... would that be good enough for you?

Comment: OfType look on instance type and return a collection of instance that can be casted to this type. We cannot cast to an interface (like ITemplateInstance<ITemplate>)!

Comment: @Jon That would be the preferable solution. However my code needs a lot of refactoring to allow covariance here

Comment: @mamuesstack: In that case, you've got a problem, because the types simply aren't compatible. You could create a non-generic base interface, but that wouldn't help you to get out the `TemplateReference` :(

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do this with:

```
List<ITemplate> allTemplates
              = objects.Where(o => o.GetType()                                                                              
                                    .GetInterfaces()
                                    .Any(i => i.IsGenericType && i.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(ITemplateInstance<>)))
                       .Select(o => o.GetType()
                                     .GetProperty("TemplateReference")
                                     .GetValue(o))
                       .OfType<ITemplate>()
                       .ToList();
```

Comment: What do you mean? It does exactly what he is asking for. It is meant to replace his "`List<ITemplate> allTemplates`..." line.

Comment: My bad... I didnt see the bottom part of the question. Sorry?!