# OfType to access Generic Parent class

Tags: c#, linq, generics, reflection, types

I have the following classes / interfaces:

- `public interface IUiCommand`
- `public class StartLandenSynchronisatieUiCommand : IUiCommand`; `public class SyncGeldverstrekkersUiCommand : IUiCommand`; etc.
- `public class RibbonButtonAggregateViewModel<TCommand> : RibbonButtonViewModel<TCommand> where TCommand : IUiCommand`
- `public abstract class RibbonButtonViewModel<TCommand> : ResizableRibbonItem where TCommand : IUiCommand`
- Some other implemented classes of `RibbonButtonViewModel`.

`RibbonButtonViewModel` contains a property `KeyTip`.

In a UnitTest I'm working on I have a list containing two items: `RibbonButtonAggregateViewModel<StartLandenSynchronisatieUiCommand>` and `RibbonButtonAggregateViewModel<SynGeldverstrekkersUiCommand` (this is just an example, I have a lot more lists with different `IUiCommands` or other implemented classes of `RibbonButtonViewModel`).

What I want to have is this list as RibbonButtonViewModels so I can access their `KeyTip`-property in a for-each.

Based on this [SO question & answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6071325/how-to-filter-to-all-variants-of-a-generic-type-using-oftype/6071434#6071434), I am able to filter the list correctly, so I still have the list of two:

```
// `items` is the list containing the two RibbonButtonAggregateViewModels
var correctItems = items.Where(x =>
    {
        if (!x.GetType().IsGenericType) return false;
        var baseType = x.GetType().BaseType;
        if (baseType == null || !baseType.IsGenericType) return false;
        return baseType.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof (RibbonButtonViewModel<>);
    })
    .ToList();
```

Even though I filter the list correctly and get both items when they are `RibbonButtonViewModels` with `IUiCommand` as generic type, I don't get a result of `RibbonButtonViewModels` to access the `KeyTip`. I tried adding either of the following two between the `Where` and `ToList`, but both doesn't work:

- `.OfType<RibbonButtonViewModel<IUiCommand>>()` -> Results in empty list
- `.Select(x => x as RibbonButtonViewModel<IUiCommand>)` -> Results in list containing two `null`

So, how should I get a list of `RibbonButtonViewModel` to access the `KeyTip`-property when I have the child items-list. (PS: Doesn't have to be `RibbonButtonAggregateViewModel` in particular, any implemented class with the `RibbonButtonViewModel` as base is fine, as long as the list is returned as `RibbonButtonViewModels` so I can access the `KeyTip`-property.

Answer (score 2):

One possible solution is to create a new interface that's covariant:

```
public interface IViewModel<out T> where T : IUiCommand
{
    string KeyTip { get; set; }
}
```

This interface could be implemented by `RibbonButtonViewModel`:

```
public abstract class RibbonButtonViewModel<TCommand> : IViewModel<TCommand> where TCommand : IUiCommand
{
    public string KeyTip { get; set; }
}
```

After that you can use this:

```
var correctItems= items.OfType<IViewModel<IUiCommand>>().ToList()
correctItems[0].KeyTip // is valid
```

or you can use dynamic - but you'll replace compiler errors by runtime errors:

```
// `items` is the list containing the two RibbonButtonAggregateViewModels
var correctItems = items.Where(x =>
{
    if (!x.GetType().IsGenericType) return false;
    var baseType = x.GetType().BaseType;
    if (baseType == null || !baseType.IsGenericType) return false;
    return baseType.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof (RibbonButtonViewModel<>);
})
.ToList<dynamic>();
correctItems[0].KeyTip = ""; // will compile but fail at runtime if the type doesn't has such a property.
```

The trick is `.ToList<dynamic>()`.

Comment: Creating a new interface around it isn't really an option currently. The feature this UnitTest is supposed to test is barely used by the users, so it has a pretty low prio. The option with the `.ToList<dynamic>()` looks promising though, so I'll try that soon. +1 for that, and I'll let you know how it turned out.